# Firebase multi-domain support to one instance

Tags: firebase, dns, firebase-hosting

I'm hoping to use Firebase to create an application that will allow users to make their content accessible via a custom domain. This is probably best described as a similar setup to how [WordPress Multisite Domain Mapping](https://wordpress.org/support/article/wordpress-multisite-domain-mapping/) works where there would be a main site, `domain.com` and many subsites based on their content `customdomain.com` `mydomain.com` `anotherdomain.com`.

The domains (100+) would point to the same codebase + Firestore, but based on the domain - would serve different content. All content swapping would be stored within a cloud function to serve the appropriate site.

I did see [this domain limit exceeded FAQ](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7650096?hl=en) but I wasn't sure if that applies to what I'm attempting to do at a DNS level.

I'm currently doing this in an older version of the app with DigitalOcean and an individual CloudFlare site that points to the same server, but it's a major pain to setup Page Rules, SSLs, etc instead of something that could hopefully be automated.

Thanks for any info!

Comment: Firebase Hosting is not currently well-equipped for this kind of massively multi-tenant custom domain use case.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh Gotcha, thanks for the heads up. Reading through https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain would it be fair to assume that I can't still use CloudFlare as a proxy (creating each individual site through there) and point at the Firebase A records, or do I need to manually add a domain to the service for Firebase to allow traffic to it?

Comment: No, you'd need a full proxy as Firebase Hosting uses the `Host` header to determine what content to serve and will serve 404s for unrecognized hosts.